# Why Typescript Generics extending from a type with Index Signature doesn't allow to add new prop

Tags: typescript

Why I can do this?

```
interface Base {
  [key: string]: any;
}

class Class {
  constructor(arg: Base) {    
    arg.newProp = 8;
  }
}
```

But can't do this?

```
interface Base {
  [key: string]: any;
}

class Class<T extends Base> {
  constructor(arg: T) {    
    arg.newProp = 8;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because the caller can write `new Class({newProp: 0 as const})` and now you’re illegally setting a property of type `0` to `8`

Comment: @jcalz In that case you'd add `readonly` to the `interface` property, though

Comment: I don't see how `readonly` matters, but I've changed from `0` to `string` in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A specific type `X` is not treated the same as a a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `X` like `T extends X`.  Anything you do with `T` needs to be applicable to *every possible type* that is assignable to `X`.  For example, if `X` is `{a: string}`, then anything you do with `T extends X` needs to work for subtypes of `X` like `{a: string, b: number}`, or `{a: "x" | "y"}`.  If you have a variable `x` of type `X` then you can write `x.a = "hello"`, but if you have a variable `t` of type `T extends X` you *cannot* write `t.a = "hello"` because that wouldn't work if `T` turns out to be `{a: "x" | "y"}`.

---

In your example, the specific type `X` is `Base` defined as `{[k: string]: any}`, with a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) whose properties are [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#the-any-type).  That's a very loose type: it essentially means a type which might have properties of any key and any value.  And so if `arg` is of type `Base` then you can assign `arg.newProp = 8`.

But `T extends Base` is different; anything you do needs to be valid for every possible subtype of `Base`.  And since `Base` is so loose, there are lots of mutually incompatible subtypes of `Base` to choose from.  For example, `{a: string}` is a subtype of `Base`:

```
const v = { a: "hello" };
new Class(v); // okay
v.newProp = 8; // error, Property 'newProp' does not exist
```

And that type isn't known to have a `newProp` key, so the compiler complains when you try to assign `8` to its `newProp` property.  Such an assignment is probably harmless, but TS won't let you assign to keys it's not sure exist.  The fact that **`T extends Base` can lack an index signature when `Base` has one** is a bit weird, but that's why you're getting the error message you're getting.

---

Furthermore, `{newProp: string}` is a subtype of `Base`:

```
const n = { newProp: "str" };
new Class(n);
n.newProp = 8; // error, number not assignable to string
```

This is arguably a worse problem for your implementation. If the value you pass in already has a `newProp` property and `8` is not assignable to it, then your class implementation will do something undesirable.

---

Note: these problems can show up with specific types also: the `new Class(v)` and `new Class(n)` lines still compile with your non-generic version of `Class`, leading to the same unpleasant consequences as above.  TypeScript's type system is [intentionally unsound in places](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness).  So it's not like what you're doing with generics is "wrong" and the other version is "right".

It's just that TypeScript assumes you're using a generic because you want this sort of extra all-possible-subtype checking.  Inversely, if you don't want that sort of checking then you should use a specific type instead of a generic type.  Or if you do use generics, then you will need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to loosen the type checking to your liking.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDB2EMFsFMGcAdwGNoAIByB7ALgeQNbgCeqA3sKpagJajbQBOAZsmgELixrlW+oDa+aEQBcqWNga0A5gF0x4UEQDcFKgF8QvJABtOsVAGE9sWAB4AKqmgAPeqAAmBjlwB8ZNX1RJMoCQwBXJGxMBgAKcAZpMQsASg8vL0jpADpQaAB3AAUGTHhUAF5UAA5VRNRNXk1Pb18JVAA3QrJUcDEAIgALaB0dTHaKsqp0jKMTWDCG2OVUAHpZ1ExCIhqGtMycvObSuYXGXIYAGlRN+EZsEgByEdPL1AdMOFRQHGsbagktKh8-bGfm0jPDa5eAdfwDdRDSgjMb6MKgaY1UDrbIg7YzebWBgHY6gAKQABGjGer301GkEAJOjQIXEkhkIGqEBgCFYqAIxASVFo9GYbJc3BqvEEwjE-hk8laSihFS+lF0+lhpi5Xh+-iCIXCyTEAviPHKVGSKNO6KFGhq1W0dT+TSKgLaqC6PT6EJlMOMcKmGIWS2Iq2NaKKO0x+1Cx1O5yuNxBdweTxef1sH2wctqv3+dqBqLyYMkrqRmSVEwRboDWyD3qxOOe+KJDBJfzJFPAVJpmDpUlA0mAmiAA)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript only allows string or number types as index signature parameters, not generic types. Like this:

```
interface Base {
  [key: string]: any;
}

class Class<T extends Base> {
  constructor(arg: T & { newProp: number }) {
    if ("newProp" in arg) {
      arg.newProp = 8;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `if ("newProp" in arg) {` guard is redundant due to the intersection-type on `T` - if you comment out the `if` then `arg.newProp = 8;` compiles fine in strict mode.

Comment: If you want to check for the existence of newProp at run-time, not just at compile-time. For example, if arg is a user input or a result of an API call, it may not have newProp as expected, and you may want to handle that case accordingly.